# In junit how to mock literay multivmpoolutil.class?

Tags: junit, mockito, liferay

In my portlet,  I'm using  `MultiVMPoolUtil.getPortalcache("test")`

This portet needs to be tested..  For this Mockito
Mock.. Try to set portalcache  using mock of above class.. 
But mock the above class is not running  in junit
... When we mock `MultiVMPoolUtil`
The mockito junit test states that .. Cannot able to mock the  liferay 
 MultiVMpoolutil.class

```
@Mock
private MultiVmpoolutil 

@Before 
public void setup()
```

How to mock this class..  Is there any other way to slove this?

Comment: Please extend your question. For now, it's not clear what is the problem that you are facing and how to reproduce the problem

Comment: @raviR did it help ?

Answer (score 0):

Static classes can be mocked with PowerMock. It´s also my last sword for fighting against util classes. furthermore it also allows very deep manipulation opportunities, like suppressing constructors of super classes or even static initializers (helpful when mocking the `PropsUtil`).

- https://github.com/powermock/powermock
- https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Suppress-Unwanted-Behavior